# Multiple forms having same hidden attribute , cant get the actual data

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, attributes

I have 7 forms in a page with hidden attribute with same name but with different value in each case (I am using CodeIgniter):

```
echo form_open('user/submit');
$attributes2 = array('class' => $imageClass);
echo form_submit($attributes2);
echo form_hidden('id',$id);
echo form_hidden('parent',$paren);
echo form_hidden('side',$side);
form_close();
```

Now, upon submission (from any of the forms) the value of id, parent, side I get is of the last(7th) form.

How can I get the ID of the form , that was actually clicked.

Say,  I clicked the submit button of form1 , where id = 001 and in form7 id is set to 7.

After submission in post variable i am getting id = 7... which should (or, i want to) be 1.

Comment: Doesn't *sound* like you  have 7 forms...

Comment: i have just shown the structure of each form.
all the forms have this same structure.but have different values.

Comment: You haven't shown *any* structure, just a small sample of code.

Comment: Check the generated HTML, especially if the `</form>` closing tags are placed properly. If you have 7 forms that don't overlap, only the inputs of the form you submit will get transferred. If you can't figure it out, post some HTML code. The problem seems not to be related to php or codeigniter.

Comment: Yes , you are absolutely write , the problem was with </form>
I didnt put the 'echo' before form_close();
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the name attribute of the hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form1[yourFieldName]" value="yourFieldValue" />
<input type="hidden" name="form2[yourFieldName]" value="yourFieldValue" />
.
.
.
<input type="hidden" name="form7[yourFieldName]" value="yourFieldValue" />
```

This way you will have a more flexible handling of your hidden inputs on each form.
Actually, you could apply this pattern to all the fields of your forms.

Chears

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `echo` before the `form_close();`:

```
echo form_open('user/submit');
...
echo form_hidden('side', $side);
echo form_close();                //instead of just `form_close()`
```

That's why your forms remained unclosed (or should I say opened?) and overlapped, becoming one big form and only gicing you the last element with the ID.